# how to make a table responsive when it has an input

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My table does not resize when i have an input in it.

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive " cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="2">
  <tr class="info">
    <td align="left"><b>Name</b>
    </td>
    <td width="200" align="left"><b>URL</b>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#DFE9F9">
    <td align="left">
      <input class="input" name="name">
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <input class="input" size="41" name="web">
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit_add" value="Add">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the following table is not responsive.
How to make it responsive?
Thanks

Comment: Remove size="41" from input tag and width 100% to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `class="input"` with `class="form-control"`

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive " cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="2">
  <tr class="info">
    <td align="left"><b>Name</b></td>
    <td width="200" align="left"><b>URL</b></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#DFE9F9">
      <td align="left"><input class="input form-control" name="name"></td>
      <td align="left"><input class="input form-control" size="41" name="web"></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="Submit_add" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your loading in boostrap anyways, why not use the bootstrap grid system?
Very easy to implement, for example: class="col-lg-3". You can find more information on the [bootstrap - grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) page.

Goodluck